# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string in store procedure

Tags: sql

I am getting conversion error when running the below sql in store procedure becasue of some reason I can't cast into varchar

```
Declare @sql varchar(100)
Declare @ddtime datetime

set @ddtime = '2012-02-03 22:14:50.057'

set @sql = 'select * from table1 where tdate='+@ddtime

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: You are trying to select a number of records into a string? That's what your code is doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to convert the `@ddtime` to a `varchar` since you are including it in a string:

```
Declare @sql varchar(100)
Declare @ddtime datetime

set @ddtime = '2012-02-03 22:14:50.057'

set @sql =  'select * from table1 where tdate= '''+ convert(nvarchar(25), @ddtime, 121) + ''''

exec(@sql)
```

or just have you `@ddtime` as a `varchar` instead of a `datetime`.

```
Declare @ddtime varchar(25)
```

The `convert(varchar(25), @ddtime, 121)` leaves your date in the same format that you initially set it as.

[How to format datetime & date in Sql Server](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: I am also trying to execute the sql which I havn't mentioned in the question. so just updated it

Comment: @RajKumar I updated my query, you just change it from print to exec

Answer (score 1):

Change the @ddtime variable datatype to varchar. You are trying to concatenate varchar and datetime.

Comment: I am also trying to execute the sql which I havn't mentioned in the question. so just updated it

Answer (score 0):

your ddtime  is datetime

you cant concat it to string.

change

```
set @sql = 'select * from table1 where tdate='''+cast ( @ddtime as nvarchar(100))+''''
```

or

change to

```
Declare @ddtime nvarchar(100)
```

Comment: I am also trying to execute the sql which I havn't mentioned in the question. so just updated it

Comment: jsut change to exec instead of print